# Custom header renderer in JXTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingx, jxtable

I was using [`JTable#setDefaultRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer-java.lang.Class-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-) to set custom rendered in Swing.

As I understood, in `SwingX` this method should be passed an instance of `DefaultTableRenderer`. If I need a very custom drawing, I can initialize `DefaultTableRenderer` with my custom `ComponentProvider`

I.e. renderer functions were moved to provider's.

Now what to do with header?

In Swing I was doing

```
getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new MyHeaderRenderer());
```

What should I do in SwingX? Use `DefaultTableRenderer` again?

Answer (score 1):

> *As I understood, in SwingX this method should be passed an instance of `DefaultTableRenderer`*

I wouldn't say you *should / must / have to* use `DefaultTableRenderer`, because the contract is inherited from `JTable` and it requires a [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) interface compliant object.

It *can* be a `DefaultTableRenderer` and we *can* take advantage of `ComponentProvider<?>` to delegate the renderer component creation based on a `CellContext`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443943/1795530). But it also can be a [DefaultTableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) as well or any implementation that meets the interface ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18253881/1795530)).

It is true that [setDefaultRenderer(Class class, TableCellRenderer renderer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer-java.lang.Class-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-) method is overriden, not to make the renderer be a `DefaultTableRenderer` instance but to synchronize the the string representation in case the renderer is a `StringValue` interface compliant object. We can see that in the source code:

```
public class JXTable extends JTable implements TableColumnModelExtListener {

    ...

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc} <p>
     * 
     * Overridden to synchronize the string representation. If the renderer is of type
     * StringValue a mapping it will be used as converter for the class type. If not, 
     * the mapping is reset to default.
     */
    @Override
    public void setDefaultRenderer(Class<?> columnClass,
            TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        super.setDefaultRenderer(columnClass, renderer);
        getStringValueRegistry().setStringValue(
                (renderer instanceof StringValue) ? (StringValue) renderer : null, 
                        columnClass);
    }

    ...
}
```

So having said all this, I don't think you have the obligation to use `DefaultTableRenderer` in the table header either. The table header remains a [JTableHeader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html) (`getTableHeader()` method wasn't overridden as far as I know) and it still requires a [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) compliant object to be set as the default renderer.